# How to extract only subdirectory name?

Tags: php

Let's say path to my photo is: `/images/nature/photo.jpg` and I want to get only `nature`. What should I do?
I tried `dirname` but it returns `/images/nature`

Comment: have you tried to explode the string? And get the required part ?

Comment: actually no, I'll try it

Answer (score 2):

let's say the url you're getting is in string. Then you can do the following to get the "nature" from the url.

```
<?php
$str = "/images/nature/photo.jpg";
$brk = explode("/",$str);
print_r($brk[2]);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution for any numbers of directories:

```
$str = "/images/nature/photo.jpg";
print_r(basename(dirname($str)));

$str = "/images/nature/sub-nature/photo.jpg";
print_r(basename(dirname($str)));
```